# to proportion numbers from two different data frames?

Tags: r

```r
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

yesterday <- function() Sys.Date() - 1L
yesterday()

df1 <- aggregate(death ~ countryName, subset(df, day == yesterday()), sum)
df8 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hirenvadher954/Worldometers-Scraping/master/countries.csv', 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`df8` also has population information.
`df1` is the number of deaths.

How do I proportion numbers?

Example of output:

| country | death | population | rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| germany | 84 | 300254589 | 28 / 100084863 |

Comment: Which package is the `yesterday` function from?

Comment: Could you give an indication of your expected outcome?

Comment: The source file for `df8` is not at the location specified in your `read.csv()` function. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I organized the question.

Answer (score 1):

The df8 csv has many rows of similar values. Hence, the unique values need to be extracted.

```
df8 <- unique(df8)

df1$population <- df8$population[match(df1$countryName, df8$country_name)]
df1$population <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",df1$population))

df1$deathrate <- df1$death/df1$population
```

If you want to remove population from df1

```
df1 <- df1[-3]
```

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, deathrate, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 213     
gave this error. @Nohnsunderm

Comment: It is running for me. Can you see the column "population" is df1 prior to running the code for df1$deathrate?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete, working solution using `dplyr` that includes the following operations.

1. Replace `aggregate()` with a simple `filter()` on the maximum value of `day` because the data is already structured as one row per country per day,
2. Eliminate duplicate rows in population data with `distinct()`,
3. Remove commas from population data with `mutate()` and `gsub()`.

First, we'll read the data using code from the original post.

```
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df8 <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hirenvadher954/Worldometers-Scraping/master/countries.csv',
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Next, we load `dplyr`, clean the data, join, and calculate mortality rates per 1000 population.

```
library(dplyr)
df8 %>% distinct(.) %>% 
     rename(countryName = country_name) %>%
     mutate(population = as.numeric(gsub(",","",population))) -> df8

df %>% filter(day == max(day)) %>%
     inner_join(df8) %>%
     mutate(deathRate = (death / population * 1000)) -> deathRateDf
head(deathRateDf[,c("countryName","death","population","deathRate")])
```

...and the output:

```
> head(deathRateDf[,c("countryName","death","population","deathRate")])
           countryName death population   deathRate
1              Andorra    49      77142 0.635192243
2 United Arab Emirates   208    9890402 0.021030490
3          Afghanistan   136   38928346 0.003493598
4  Antigua and Barbuda     3      97929 0.030634439
5             Anguilla     0      14869 0.000000000
6              Albania    31    2877797 0.010772129
>
```

**NOTE:** there are 38 countries where the population data did not match to the country name in the covid-19 reporting data, suggesting that additional data cleaning is required.

```
# number of countries in pop data that didn't match to covid-19 data
nrow(df8) - nrow(deathRateDf)
df8$countryName[!df8$countryName %in% deathRateDf$countryName]
```

...and the output:

```
> nrow(df8) - nrow(deathRateDf)
[1] 38
> df8$countryName[!df8$countryName %in% deathRateDf$countryName]
 [1] "Holy See"                 "Niue"                     "Tokelau"                  "Nauru"                    "Saint Pierre & Miquelon"  "Saint Helena"            
 [7] "Tuvalu"                   "Wallis & Futuna"          "Cook Islands"             "Palau"                    "Turks and Caicos"         "Faeroe Islands"          
[13] "Saint Kitts & Nevis"      "American Samoa"           "Northern Mariana Islands" "Marshall Islands"         "Tonga"                    "U.S. Virgin Islands"     
[19] "St. Vincent & Grenadines" "Micronesia"               "Kiribati"                 "Samoa"                    "Guam"                     "Sao Tome & Principe"     
[25] "Vanuatu"                  "Brunei "                  "Cabo Verde"               "Solomon Islands"          "Macao"                    "Comoros"                 
[31] "Lesotho"                  "Puerto Rico"              "State of Palestine"       "Congo"                    "Turkmenistan"             "Czech Republic (Czechia)"
[37] "CÃ´te d'Ivoire"           "North Korea"             
>
```